# Eclipse Manipulating project explorer Context Menu Dynamically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an action provide. In fillContextMenu, I am trying to iterate all the menu items available with IMenuManager.getItems() method. I am unable to get full menu list.

For example, Import and Export context menus are not available through getItems().

Does it hide contributions added through 'popupMenus' extension.

Is there a way to iterate through all the menus which are associated with a given menu manager.

Thanks.

Phani.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that when calling getItems() on a IMenuManager it will only return its child items and not child items of other IMenuManagers that are added to your root IMenuManager. If you want to get all items and child IMenuManager items here is a function that will do that. Although if you are doing this to add IContributionItems you can simply use the .addItem(item itemPath) which will internally walk the graph and add your contribution in the right place. If you want to remove an exisiting contribution you need to first get all the contribution items in the menu tree and then call remove() on the IMenuManager with the instance of the ContributionItem you want to remove. Try this function and you will see the Import and Export items as well as other sub menu items in your root manager. Hope that helps, if you're still stuck please reply. - Duncan Krebs

```
    private IContributionItem[] getMenuTreeItems(IMenuManager rootManager) {
        List<IContributionItem> items = new ArrayList<IContributionItem>();
        addMenuManagerItems(rootManager, items);
        return items.toArray(new IContributionItem[items.size()]);

    }

    private void addMenuManagerItems(IMenuManager manager, List<IContributionItem> items ) { 
        for (IContributionItem item : manager.getItems()) {
            if (item instanceof IMenuManager) {
                IMenuManager childManager = (IMenuManager) item;
                addMenuManagerItems(childManager, items);
            } else { 
                items.add(item); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duncan Krebs, I am doing the same as you suggested. Even though there are sub menus, which I can see in popup, they are not visible through code. I am getting some contribution items, separators, and groups only through code and no menu managers.